# Log4cplus minimal locking

Tags: logging, log4cplus

When i use RollingFileAppender with Log4cplus,Log4cplus "LOCK" the file.

> How can  set "minimal" lock so that it does NOT LOCK the file?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Are you running on Windows? Why do you want it not to lock the file?

Comment: Yes, I use windows. Well, first i do not want my logging crash.[ some other process may write it also].I my lose some data but not want a crash. And i want users able to delete log file when they want and when there is something to log the logger should create new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4cplus supports synchronization between processes only in trunk, you would have to get version 1.1.0-RC2. Log4cplus keeps log files open the whole time the appender it belongs to exists, so log files on Windows are likely not deletable. Having the option to open log file only on demand is interesting idea. I would suggest logging into separate files for each processes to avoid the need for the locking and to make deleting files easier.